# Grep dates from file and format them

Tags: bash, date, debian

I have a file "tmp.txt" looking like that:

```
random text random text 25/06/2021 15:15:15
random text random text 26/06/2021 15:15:15
random text random text 26/06/2021 15:15:15
```

and I would like to:

1. extract all datetimes
2. add 4 hours
3. display them as timestamp

I didn't figured out yet how to add hour as I,m facing an issue with the date format not being recognized by the date function.

(I would like to be able to do it with a single line command if possible)

Here is my current command:

```
egrep -o "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" tmp.txt | while read -r line ; do echo $(date -d  "$line" +%s);done
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: `date` is probbably assuming MM/DD/YYYY. Try date with debug first:  `date --debug -d "06/26/2021 15:15:15 4 hours" +%s`

Comment: `perl -MPOSIX -nE 'while (m{(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)}g){ say strftime("%s",$6,$5,($4+4),$1,$2,($3-1900)) }' tmp.txt`

Comment: Thanks @jhnc ! Is there a way to print each time the rest of the line with the timestamp instead of the initial date?

Comment: btw I have a doubt in the result.
I have tested to replace +4 by +6 to test with 6 hours extra and it returns 1627240515 but the result is supposed to be 1624648515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tried and Tested, Minimal Solution

You can use the below command line to get the desired result. I have tested it with your example and it worked as expected on my Linux machine.

```
egrep -o "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" tmp.txt | while read -r line; do dd=${line:0:2}; mm=${line:3:2}; yyyy=${line:6:4}; time=${line:11:8}; date -d "${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd} ${time} 4 hours" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'; done
```

I'll break it down into multiple lines so it's easy to understand:

```
egrep -o "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" tmp.txt \
| \
while read -r line; do
# Reading date and time into separate variables
dd=${line:0:2};
mm=${line:3:2};
yyyy=${line:6:4};
time=${line:11:8};
# Adding 4 hours and displaying datetime in desired format
date -d "${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd} ${time} 4 hours" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
done
```

To add 4 hours, you can just mention it after the datetime in -d option as shown above, I tried with hours, minute and days and it worked as expected

For your input file tmp.txt:

```
random text random text 25/06/2021 15:15:15
random text random text 26/06/2021 15:15:15
random text random text 26/06/2021 15:15:15
```

On running my command, the output was:

```
2021-06-25 19:15:15
2021-06-26 19:15:15
2021-06-26 19:15:15
```

I tested it with edge cases like close to midnight time, leap years etc and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestion! I would like to display the date as a timestamp (seconds) so I replaced "+'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'" by "%s".

Answer (score 0):

Let me adjust the timestamps to make the output more interesting:

```
$ cat tmp.txt
random text random text 25/06/2021 15:15:15
random text random text 26/06/2021 20:15:15
random text random text 26/06/2021 23:15:15
```

@jhnc has the right idea: use a language that's both good at text manipulation and can do date arithmetic. I'd use Time::Piece

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
    m{(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)} or continue;
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d/%m/%Y %T");
    $t += 4 * 3600;
    print $t->strftime("%F %T")
' tmp.txt
```

```
2021-06-25 19:15:15
2021-06-27 00:15:15
2021-06-27 03:15:15
```

Or, here's perl piping into xargs for the date stuff

```
perl -pe 's{.*(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*}
           {$2/$1/$3 +4 hours $4}
' tmp.txt | xargs -I DT date -d DT '+%F %T'
```

```
2021-06-25 19:15:15
2021-06-27 00:15:15
2021-06-27 03:15:15
```